# Mix Dynamic class with data binders in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, openweathermap

So I have the following v-for in a HTML:

```
<ul v-for="(item, index) in openweathermap.list">
    <li>{{item.dt_txt}}</li>
    <li>{{item.weather[0].description}}</li>
    <li>{{item.weather[0].id}}</li>
    <li>{{item.main.temp}}&deg;C</li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is to add an icon to these information, like font awesome.

So I found these: `<i class="owf owf-200"></i>`  This will serve me just right but the number must change dynamically. So the number is the `{{item.weather[0].id}}` in the v-for.

My question is this; How can I mix these two together?

I tried something like this `<i class="owf owf-{{item.weather[0].id}}"></i>`
but it obviously has wrong syntax.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `v-bind:class` - which allows you to append two strings, just like in Javascript. So the value should be `'owf owf-' + item.weather[0].id`.

In the snippet, I've done that with dummy data and color changes for two different classes, but you should get the idea.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{ 
    items: [
      {
        weather: [{ id: 200 }],
        txt: "Some text"
      },
      {
        weather: [{ id: 300 }],
        txt: "Some other text"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.owf.owf-200 {
  color: red;
}

.owf.owf-300 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="item in items">
    <span v-bind:class="'owf owf-' + item.weather[0].id">
      {{ item.txt }}
    </span>  
    <br />
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you mate! I read about v-bind but still couldn't get the right syntax for some reason. So in my case, `<i v-bind:class="'owf owf-' + item.weather[0].id">` works! 
You can even write it like this: `<i :class="'owf owf-' + item.weather[0].id">`